# Problem designing test for NestWhile?

Tags: iteration

I am trying to use NestWhile with a custom test as follows:

```
k = {{Subscript[\[Lambda], s], {s, s}}, {Subscript[\[Lambda],x], {x, x}}};
SubscriptQ[x_] := (ToString[Head[x]] == "Subscript")
NestWhile[First, k, SubscriptQ[#] &]
```

But it does not work. I want it to keep taking the first element of the list until some Subscript appears. How can I make a test for this?

Comment: @user444, I would like to guide you to [_When should I edit posts?_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/editing) (namely _"Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged"_). Also, I don't think contractions are considered grammatical _mistakes_ :)

Comment: @user444 - I have to agree with Domen here.  Not a [single one of your edits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/84456/user444?tab=activity) seems to improve the questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html) will stop when the condition is `False`. Therefore, you have to negate your condition!

Also, no need for `ToString`.

```
SubscriptQ[x_] := Head[x] === Subscript

k = {{Subscript[λ, s], {s, s}}, {Subscript[λ, x], {x, x}}};
NestWhile[First, k, Not@*SubscriptQ]
(* Subscript[λ, s] *)
```